# Search within results of a SQL function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to search within the second column of my table. I am using STUFF function in SQL to combine all `LastNames` with the same `FirstName`. So here is my query:

```
SELECT a.FirstName, 
STUFF(
(SELECT N', ' + b.LastName 
FROM NameChange b 
WHERE a.NameID = b.NameID 
FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'')
 AS 'LastNames' 
FROM Names a ORDER BY a.FirstName
```

The above query works just the way I want it to. But when I add in a `WHERE` clause (before the `ORDER BY`), I get an error that says

> Invalid column name 'LastNames'

I have tried to do this several ways. I have tried searching by just `b.LastName`, `LastName`, `[LastName]`, `LastNames`, `b.LastNames`, `[LastNames]`, `b.[LastName]`, and `b.[LastNames]`

I don't know what else I can try to get this to work. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy way to do this is put your query in a cte.

```
with MyNames as
(
    SELECT a.FirstName, 
    STUFF(
    (SELECT N', ' + b.LastName 
    FROM NameChange b 
    WHERE a.NameID = b.NameID 
    FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'')
     AS 'LastNames' 
    FROM Names a 
)

select *
from MyNames n
where LastNames = 'Some Name' 
ORDER BY n.FirstName
```

Comment: That worked very well. Thank you very much. I will mark it as the answer.